# Phonegap Windows Phone 8 font anti-aliasing

Tags: css, cordova, windows-phone-8, fonts

Is it possible to smooth fonts on a Phonegap + jQuery Mobile + Windows Phone 8 app?

As you can see in the attached screenshots, the same page is shown differently on Android and Windows Phone.

The page displayed in an Android phone has anti-aliased fonts, but on Windows Phone the fonts looks pixelated.

I've tried lots of css font anti-aliased properties, but it didn't work:

```
<style type="text/css">
  html, body, ui-body-a, ui-body-b, ui-body-c, ui-body-d, ui-body-e, ui-body-f {
    -webkit-font-smoothing:antialiased !important;
    -moz-font-smoothing:antialiased !important;
    -ms-font-smoothing:antialiased !important;
    -o-font-smoothing:antialiased !important;
    -font-smoothing:antialiased !important;
    font-smooth: always !important;
  }
</style>
```

Is there a way to fix it on Windows Phone 8?

[image]

[image]

Comment: this test page can be accessed at http://easytef.com/mobile/test1.html

Answer (score -1):

It just happened that Microsoft implemented font anti-aliasing on Windows Phone 8.1. It's a platform behavior....